# Calling a member function of class using objects giving lookup error

Tags: c++, class, boost, shared-libraries, header-files

I am trying to build plugins in c++ using boost library. **helper.h**
Header file:

```
    #include <string>
    #ifndef HELPER_H
    #define HELPER_H

    class Helper
    {
        public:
        std::string s;
        void helper_new(std::string a);
    };

    #endif
```

I defined the member function in a file  **helper.cpp**

```
    #include "helper.h"
    namespace boostfs = boost::filesystem;
    namespace boostdll = boost::dll;
    namespace dll = boost::dll;


    // Member Functions() 
    void Helper::helper_new(std::string a) 
    { 
        //int i=0;
        std::cout<<"Inside helper_new function!!";
        std::cout<<"\n";
        std::cout<<a;
        std::cout<<"\n";
        /*std::ofstream MyFile("/home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/outputs/helper.txt");
        std::cout << "Writing in helper.txt\n"; */
        /*for(i=0;i<LONG_MAX;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<LONG_MAX;j++);*/
        /*MyFile<<a+" ";
        MyFile<<i;
        MyFile<<"\n";
        MyFile.close();*/
        std::cout << "Done\n"; 
    } 
int main() {

    Helper obj;
    std::string a;
    std::cout<<"Enter string u want to write?";
    std::getline(std::cin, a);
    obj.s=a;

    int choice=1;
    std::cout<<"which strat to use? \'1\' or \'2\' ?(default is 1)";
    std::cin>>choice;

    std::string file="strat"+std::to_string(choice);
    boostfs::path lib_path = boostfs::current_path();
    boost::filesystem::path p2(std::string(lib_path.string()).append("/plugins/").append(file).append(".so"));



    boost::shared_ptr<plugin_api> plugin;            // variable to hold a pointer to plugin variable
    std::cout << "Loading the plugin" << std::endl;

    plugin = dll::import<plugin_api>(          // type of imported symbol is located between `<` and `>`
        p2,                     // path to the library and library name
        "plugin",                                       // name of the symbol to import
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations              // makes `libmy_plugin_sum.so` or `my_plugin_sum.dll` from `my_plugin_sum`
    );

    plugin->handle_task(obj);

    std::cout << plugin->print() << std::endl;
}
```

I called the member function from another file with the help of object of Helper class passed to it as argument(this is compiles as so file) **strat1.cpp**

```
#include "../helper.h"
#include <string>
namespace my_namespace {

class strat : public plugin_api {
public:
    strat() {
        std::cout << "Constructing start" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string print() const {
        return "Hello from strat 1";
    }

    int handle_task(Helper a) {
        //long i=0;

        //std::ofstream fout;
        //fout.open("/home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/outputs/strat1.txt");
        std::cout<<"Inside strat 1";
        std::cout<<"\n";
        /*for(i=0;i<LONG_MAX;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<LONG_MAX;j++);*/
        //fout<<a.s+" ";
        //fout<<i;
        //fout<<"\n";
        //fout.close();

        std::cout<<a.s;
        std::cout<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"going to the helper class function.";
        std::string p="Hello man. What's up?";
        a.helper_new(p); //error is here
        return 0;
    }

    ~strat() {
        std::cout << "Destructing strat ;o)" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

I am getting this error `./a.out: symbol lookup error: /home/deepansh/Desktop/Plugin_example/plugins/strat1.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Helper10helper_newENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

When compiling the code can someone help. compiling:

1. Convert the plugin library(plugin implementation) to object file by using:

`gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic strat1.c ../helper.cpp`   //here -wall and -Werror are for warnings

2. Then convert the .o files to .so files using(creating shared library from object file) :

`gcc -shared -o strat1.so strat1.o`

3. `g++-8 helper.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_filesystem -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -ldl`

when I run the executable a.out the error occurs

Comment: Can you edit your question to show which files contain the bottom two code blocks and how you compile your "strat1.so" ?

Comment: So the obvious explanation would be that you aren't compiling or aren't linking the file containing `helper_new`.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but why is `#include <string>` outside the include guards in helper.h? It should be inside.

Comment: @Botje I have edited the question with file names and compile steps. please see and point out the problem if possiblr..

Comment: @john I have added the compile steps, do you see a problem with the linking? and yeah `#include <string>` should be inside.

Comment: Look at step 2. Where did `helper.o` go?

Comment: @Botje I added the complete `helper.cpp` file as you can see it requires `strat1.so`(compiled `strat1.cpp`) for compiling, how can `helper.cpp`(to `helper.o`) compile it first?

Comment: @DeepanshNagaria You need to add helper.o to strat1.so, like this `gcc -shared -o strat1.so strat1.o helper.o`. You compiled helper.cpp but you didn't link it, which is exactly what the error message is telling you. In C++ files are compiled separately, then they **all** need to be linked together at the end.